# Apache Tomcat 6.0 Tomcat6 service stopped unexpectedly in windows server 2012

Tags: tomcat6, windows-server-2012

We have .Net application consuming tomcat solr3.5 services and deployed on Windows Server 2012. Its is 64 bit machine with 32 GB RAM and Tomcat veriosn is 6 and is installed at :"C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0". During the peak load, the solr sevice stops/unresponsive and it is happening very frequently. We didnt fount any erro logs in windows event viewer but in tomcat logs we got the following exception :

> Aug 06, 2014 10:51:18 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software
>   caused connection abort: socket write error   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.solr.common.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:55)  at
>   org.apache.solr.common.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:50)  at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.startTag(XMLWriter.java:269)   at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writePrim(XMLWriter.java:780)  at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeInt(XMLWriter.java:691)   at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeVal(XMLWriter.java:565)   at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeNamedList(XMLWriter.java:621)
>     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeVal(XMLWriter.java:594)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeNamedList(XMLWriter.java:621)
>     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeVal(XMLWriter.java:594)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeNamedList(XMLWriter.java:621)
>     at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeVal(XMLWriter.java:594)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeResponse(XMLWriter.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.response.XMLResponseWriter.write(XMLResponseWriter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket
>   write error   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native
>   Method)   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:761)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:598)
>     at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
>     ... 36 more
>
> Aug 06, 2014 10:51:29 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.ExactPhraseScorer.(ExactPhraseScorer.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:577)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:364)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListAndSetNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1408)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1158)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:362)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:378)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Aug 07, 2014 11:53:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint
>   createWorkerThread INFO: Maximum number of threads (200) created for
>   connector with address null and port 8080

Can anyone help on this error ?

Comment: It clearly says the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at. Give some your effort

Answer (score 0):

Please re-configure XMS & XMX value in Java_OPTS